# Passing variables between classes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have two files, one called `a.rb` and one called `b.rb`. Here's the contents in both:

```
# a.rb
class A
    def initialize
        @variable = ""

        @module_b = B.new(self)
    end

    def pass_to_b(self)
        @module_b.do_something(@variable)
    end

    def set_variable(var)
        # var = empty
        @variable = var
    end
end
```

and

```
# b.rb
class B
    def initialize(module_a)
        @module_a = module_a
    end

    def set_variable_in_a(data)
        @module_a.set_variable(data)
    end

    def do_something(variable)
        # variable = empty
        set_variable_in_a("hello world")
    end
end
```

This is just an example of what I'm dealing with. If I'm trying to start a function in Class A, which is supposed to do something in ClassB and then change an instance variable in Class A, I'm not sure how to do this properly. This is what I've tried, however:

```
a = A.new
a.pass_to_b
```

Class B cannot see the instance variable `@variable`, and if it tries to `set_variable_in_a`, that doesn't work either. It's like the `do_something` function in Class A successfully calls the `do_something` function in Class B, but the instance variable information is not available. I thought by passing `self` to Class B, we'd be able to *at least* call the function

Comment: When you say "the instance variable information is not available", what do you mean? You're passing it's _value_ as the argument _variable_.

Comment: Why can't `B#do_something` return a value instead? Or `A#pass_to_b` could pass itself to `B#do_something` and `do_something` could call methods on its argument to send information back to the `A` instance.

Comment: What you are trying to build is basically a [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) which is considered an antipattern and should be avoided. The correct way would be that `do_something` just returns a result and that A assigns the result to the instance variable on itself.

Comment: If you remove `(self)` from `def pass_to_b`, your code works just fine: calling `a.pass_to_b` sets the instance variable `@variable` to `"hello world"`.

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments. I realized that one of my instance variables had a typo and so I was having an issue. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My MRI throws exeption about

```
def pass_to_b(self)
```

because you can't pass self to method as argument.

You need delete 'self' how argument

Run code below and you will see that @variable of instance of Class A has '123hello world' string

```
class A
  def initialize
    @variable = "123"

    @module_b = B.new(self)
  end

  def pass_to_b
    @module_b.do_something(@variable)
  end

  def set_variable(var)
    # var = empty
    @variable = var
  end
end

# b.rb
class B
  def initialize(module_a)
    @module_a = module_a
  end

  def set_variable_in_a(data)
    @module_a.set_variable(data)
  end

  def do_something(variable)
    set_variable_in_a(variable + "hello world")
  end
end

a = A.new
a.pass_to_b
```

display variable 'a' and you will see something like this

```
#<A:0x00007fdaba0f3c90 @variable="123hello world", @module_b=#<B:0x00007fdaba0f3c40 @module_a=#<A:0x00007fdaba0f3c90 ...>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. I realized I had a typo in the way I was defining my instance variable. This helped out!